# Why would the council not cut off Nak-su?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

When it looks as if Jang-Wook might not show up for his duel, the council of mages gets together and discusses what to do with him. Apparently, if all the members of the council of mages voted to cast him out, he would actually be cut off from the flow of energy and lose his powers as a mage. Given the situation, we can probably assume that this would work even if they did not know where he was.

As such, why did they not do this to Nak-su? She was an assassin who was killing numerous mages, so one presumes that unanimity would not have been difficult to achieve. Is it possible for a mage to be too powerful to be cut off? Or were they unable or unwilling to target her for some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because they would have to catch her first.

As of the end of the first season, we have seen no particular evidence of the council being able to cut people off from the flow of energy simply by voting, even though there have been many cases where that would have been useful (Shaman Choi when she first started using sorcery, Jin Mu when he was on the run, and so forth). We have, however, seen that even a single powerful mage could theoretically destroy someone's flow of energy by casting a spell on them "in person," as Jang Gang threatened to do with Jin Mu in the past. As such, it seems most likely that the council could *not* take away Uk's powers simply by voting, but rather that  if the council unanimously voted to take away his powers, they would track him down, and one or more of the powerful mages on the council would destroy his flow of energy. After all, both Seo Yul and Dang Gu knew where he was and were able to find him without any problem. He was not precisely in hiding. The unanimous vote would be necessary not because of any direct supernatural element, but because taking away a mage's powers is a rather extreme move, particularly with the Gwanju away.

In Naksu's case, she was hard to track down, and probably too powerful even for most of the mages on the council to take on alone, so they would have had to subdue her to have a good chance of successfully casting a spell to destroy her ability to cast spells. Presumably they would simply have preferred to kill her by that point.